# How do i concat an array with a different array which uses of local storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, concatenation

`Datalist` is an array I'm trying to `concat` the boards array with the `Datalist` array, but when I console it doesn't reflect. On the other hand when I assign `Datalist.concat(boards)` to a variable it reflects example

```js
const newArr = Datalist.concat(boards);
console.log(newArr)
```

(main code) please help me review it. Thanks in advance

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Modal from './Modal';
import { Datalist } from '../Data/Boards';

function Boards() {
  const [boards, setboards] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('boards')) || []);
  const [title, settitle] = useState('');
  localStorage.setItem('boards', JSON.stringify(boards));

  Datalist.concat(boards);
  console.log(Datalist);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    settitle(e.target.value);
  };
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    if (title.length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    setboards((prev) => [...prev, title]);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <ul id="boards">
        <BoardList boards={boards} />
      </ul>
      <Modal title={title} handleChange={handleChange} handleSubmit={handleSubmit} />
    </div>
  );
}
function BoardList({ boards }) {
  const history = useHistory();
  return (
    <>
      {boards.map((board, index) => (
        <li
          key={index}
          onClick={() => {
            history.push('./workspace');
          }}
        >
          <h3>{board}</h3>
        </li>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
export default Boards;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the expected behaviour. The `concat` function does not alter the original arrays. You can read about it in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

For your case you should be able to do `Datalist = Datalist.concat(boards);` and it should work like you're expecting

Comment: it gives Datalist is not defined, Thanks